# ASP editor and debugger (step by step?)

Tags: asp-classic

I´ve got in front of my eyes a project build by another guy and it is developed in ASP (not ASP.NET) so I opened it with Visual Web Developer 2010 and I can edit but it isn´t posible to debug it step by step, it´s always looking for aspx pages...

do you know any other editor for asp? thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use Visual Studio 2010 to debug ASP pages

First configure IIS as follows ...

1. Go to IIS Manager
2. Switch to Features View
3. Double-click ASP (under IIS heading)
4. Open up the Debugging Properties section
5. Set Enable Server-side Debugging to True

To debug your ASP page ...

1. Run your website without debugging it
2. Wait for your web browser appears
3. In VS select Attach to Process... from the Debug menu
4. Tick the Show processes in all session box (below the list of Available Processes)
5. Find the w3wp.exe process (it's the one with Script, T-SQL, Managed, x86 in the Type column)
6. Click the Attach button
7. Set your breakpoint
8. ..................................reproduce the problem

Now, this is in full Visual Studio, but it may work in the express edition.

Comment: ey! thank you!! i´ll try.. i only have express edition...so.. i´ll tell you

Comment: ah, you're using a slightly older version of IIS that I am. I think if you can find the "application" part of the configuration, the one where you can set the session timeout. I think it's in there somewhere that you can turn on server side debugging.

Comment: yep! i found it! now VST part

Comment: ok... maybe i need non express VST because this one doens´t have Attach to process option...

Comment: this is from the help in IIS ... Enable ASP Server-Side Script Debugging

Select this check box to enable the Web server to enter the Microsoft Script Debugger while processing ASP pages. You can then use the debugger to examine your scripts.

Enabling ASP server-side debugging causes ASP to run in single-threaded mode. For performance reasons, ASP debugging is not recommended in a production environment.